# Increase Chart Size of WPF Chartingtoolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, toolkit

Im currently working on a little Project, where i make use of the WPF Charting Toolkit.

[now im a bit annoyed by these huge margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMOXZ.jpg)

```
<ch:Chart Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Chart">
        <ch:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type vt:Legend}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ch:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <ch:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding WeightChartData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" />
            <ch:Chart.Axes>
            <ch:LinearAxis Minimum="{Binding MinVal}" Maximum="{Binding MaxVal}" Orientation="Y"/>
        </ch:Chart.Axes>
    </ch:Chart>
```

this is the XAML from the chart.

is there any way i can make the Chart bigger

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the margins more comfortable, you have to create a new style for the Chart. Easiest way is to copy the original Chart style completely and modify it to meet your needs.

The [original style is available from GitHub](https://github.com/jrwren/wpftoolkit/blob/master/DataVisualization/Themes/generic.xaml). From that file you can find Style TargetType="charting:Chart", where the large margins are defined. For example:

```
<Setter Property="LegendStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,15,0" />
```

Alternatively, you can check the following SO post for a "bare minimum" chart style and to modify it for your needs: [Change margin around plot area and title in WPF Toolkit chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595310/change-margin-around-plot-area-and-title-in-wpf-toolkit-chart)